# Как показать один элемент списка ListView в другом Activity

Tags: android, listview

Есть главная активность. В нем ListView со своим адаптером. Элемент ListView состоит из разных объектов (TextView, Button и т.д).

При нажатии на элемент списка мы переходим на другую активность, в которой должны отобразить именно этот элемент в таком же формате.

Есть шаблон элемента xml откуда адаптер черпает вьюшки.

Вопрос: Есть ли какие нибудь функции, которые могут с этим помочь.
Была идея просто передать данные конкретного элемента с адаптера и в новой активности заново построить по этим данным и шаблону View.

Ищу способ проще. Так как кругозор SDK пока не позволяет даже правильно подать запрос в google.

Маленькая схема для представления результата:
[image]

Comment: данные айтема , которые нужно отобразить в другом активити что это ? запись в БД , строка в массиве , объект модели .. ?  Вообще есть стандартный паттерн Mater/Detail - он входит даже в сэмплы обоих IDE  Здесь в общем то только два варианта - либо интент в другую активити , либо колбек туда же , интент в данном случае предпочтительнее и проще

Comment: Это объект модели

Answer (score 2):

Просто передаешь intent со всеми параметрами itemview в другую activity.

Для курсора я пользовался такой процедурой:

```
    public static void putCursorToIntent(Cursor mCurs,Intent intent) {

    for (int idx=0;idx<mCurs.getColumnCount();idx++) {                          
        String columName=mCurs.getColumnName(idx);                          
        switch (mCurs.getType(idx)) {
            case android.database.Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                break;
            case android.database.Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:                                        
                intent.putExtra(columName, mCurs.getLong(idx));                 
                break;
            case android.database.Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                intent.putExtra(columName, mCurs.getDouble(idx));                   
                break;
            case android.database.Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                intent.putExtra(columName, mCurs.getString(idx));                   
                break;
            default:                            
        }

    }       
}
```

Для xml так же можно написать, но сходу нет примера.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас есть несколько вариантов как это сделать, но хотелось бы точнее описание Вашего объекта в списке.

А именно надо ли Вам представление этого объекта в том виде, в котором оно хранится в `ListView`.

Допустим Вам нужно всего лишь передать строку или число, то Вам всего лишь это и нужно сделать.Но если Вам нужен именно такой объект,например `View` или `Drawable` (обычно изображения не передают, а рендарят прямо в новом активити, хотя иногда бывает менее затратно все таки передать объект существующий в памяти).

Обычно алгоритм передачи для обоих случаев одинаков. Есть механизм для взаимодействия между `Activity`, через тот же объект с помощью которого Вы ее и создаете - `Intent`.

Вот небольшой пример.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("id or tag for object", mObjectToPass);
```

И соответственно получаем в другом `Activity`

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
    YourCustomObject mReceivedObject=(YourCustomObject)i.getParcelableExtra("id or tag for object");
```

Но Вам следует учесть что Ваш объект должен реализовать интерфейс [Paracable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) или же [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html). То есть Вы должны написать как следует запаковать и распаковать объект.

О разнице между этими двумя интерфейсами думаю без проблем можно почитать в гугле.

Также передавать можно не только объекты, а и примитивы, строки. Для этого существуют соответствующее методы класса `Intent`(`getStringExtra(),getIntExtra() ...`) Тогда Вам уже не надо заниматься упаковкой объектов.

Если есть вопросы задавайте.

З.Ы Такие методы как статические глобальные переменные не рассматриваю, думаю понятно по каким причинам.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Этот вариант я рассматривал. Мне нужно передать число и drawable объект.
Не могли бы вы посмотреть вот эту мою проблему?
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415851/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-button-%D0%B8%D0%B7-listview-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80