# Как изменить Button из Listview через адаптер?

Tags: android, listview

Есть ListView

Есть класс Item

Есть класс MyAdapter

Список состоит из модульных объектов.
Как поменять свойство элемента , к примеру, Button в этом списке?

В функции getView адаптера к кнопке ставим бекграунд.

Там же в адаптере есть функция updatecurrentitem . Ее я вызываю с другой активности.

Как мне найти кнопку конкретного элемента и поменять ее свойство?

Comment: Мало кто читает ВСЕ вопросы на этом ресурсе , как правило их фильтруют по тегам интересующей темы , чтобы вопрос попал по назначению ставьте общий тег раздела , в данном случае [android] , потом уже уточняющие , если нужно . Иначе ваш вопрос может остаться незамеченным

Comment: как другая активити связана с адаптером?
она открывается по нажатию кнопки из строки ListView с этим адаптером?

Comment: В другом активити мы прописываем зачения которые потом через MainActivity летят в функцию в адаптере public void updateCurrentItem(int id, float f) 
То есть эта функция в мейн активити вызывается как то так. 
adapter.updateCurrentItem(int id, float f)

Answer (score 2):

Адаптер СОЗДАЕТ view для отображения в списке , когда список запрашивает требуемый ему пункт для отображения . Изменения view в адаптере не будут отображаться , пока список вновь не запросит эту позицию - это может случиться не очень скоро.
Чтобы обновить айтем уже после создания , вам надо получить доступ к его уже созданному адаптером view , это решается уже не через переопределение getView() в адаптере , а через доступ к нужному view "снаружи" , затем уже из этого вью добываете кнопку и меняете ей фон на новый .

```
int visiblePosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = listView.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
Button button  = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);//id кнопки в разметке айтема
button.setBackground(background);// вставить свое значение для фона
```

Так же не забудьте обновить данные в самой модели

Вторым вариантом решения вашего вопроса может быть следующая схема :

1.Изменяете нужное значение в коллекции объектов (модели), которую передаете в адаптер 
2.Делаете `listView.notifyDataSetChanged();` - это заставит адаптер пересоздать view айтемов списка используя текущие данные

Какой из способов предпочтительнее - решать вам , в зависимости от конкретных условий реализации . Второй способ , естественно , более нагруженный для устройства и обычно используется , когда нужно обновить многие (все) айтемы списка разом - он влияет на содержимое всего списка

Comment: Проблема в том что лист состоит из объекта в котором для каждой кнопки рисуется свой бекграуд объектом drawable. 
Мне нужно найти способ вызывать метод для конкретной кнопки. Зная позицию элемента в списке.

Comment: Все правильно. Я и так делал. Проблема вот в чем :
Вот это значение drawable меняется в другом активити.
Я научился кнопки перерисовывать по нажатию.
Но мне нужно потом перерисовать ее просто по вызову функции , или как нибудь еще. Всмысле обновить после изменения вот этого drawable В другом месте. То есть в списке данные я меняю а как обновить view (в моем случае Button) что бы он скушал новое значение и перерисовался я не знаю

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Вылетает с ошибкой. В компиляторе видно что он пытается взять слой layot вместо button. View состоит из текста и кнопки. Нужно именно вытянуть кнопку..

Comment: Вам нужно просто поменять фон у нажимаемой кнопки и все ?

Comment: Нет. У меня есть список этих кнопок. Мне нужно заного вызвать для конкретной кнопки из списка функцию setBackground . Как она вызывается в getView , выше код. Просто нужно найти эту кнопку или заного как то обновить все элементы. я уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: снова обновил ответ